# Close a modal form clicking on a transparent area

Tags: forms, onclick, transparent

I have a modal form that covers completely the screen. This form has has transparentColor = TRUE and transparentColorValue = form's color, so its transparent except the areas with different color.
Is there a way to fire up the onClick event when i click on the transparent area ?

Answer (score 0):

I found that, if form has some colors like clCream, clActiveCaption,clSkyBlue etc then its transparent area is clickable !